# Is there a way to modify the Session Timeout in CRM 2011 Online

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, session-timeout, dynamics-crm-online

We have a client using a hosted (crm on-demand) system, and they would like to adjust the session timeout for users.  I've seen ways to do this for and IFD deployment, but can this be done with the "cloud" version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the timeout settings, you need to have access to the Security Token Service (STS), which is responsible for the creation of the security tokens.

In case of Dynamics CRM Online this is Windows Live ID. IMHO, because of this constellation, there is no possibility to change the timeout value.